# SQL Server NULL replacement with dynamic value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-17

I am looking to replace NULL values with a mode value based on data within a table.

In the following example I would like to replace the NULL InDate of the EquipmentID with the mode value of the InDates for that ProcessID. I have calculated the mode InDate for a ProcessID, I just can't work out how to use that value to replace the NULL value for the EquipmentID withing the ProcessID

Here is an example setup:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_basic (
                InDate INT,
                EquipmentID INT,
                ProcessID nvarchar(50),
                SiteID INT
                )

INSERT INTO Table_basic (InDate, EquipmentID, ProcessID, SiteID)
VALUES (2001, 1,'1PAA',1),
        (2001,2,'1PAA',1),
        (NULL, 3,'1PAA',1),
        (2001,4,'1PAA',1),
        (1999, 5,'1PAA',1),
        (2001,6,'1PAB',1),
        (2001,7,'1PAC',1),
        (2001, 8,'2AA',2),
        (1999,9,'2AB',2),
        (NULL, 10,'2AB',2),
        (1999,11,'2AB',2),
        (1998,12,'2AB',2),
        (2001, 13,'2AB',2),
        (1999,14,'2AB',2),
        (2001, 15,'2AC',2),
        (2001,16,'2AC',2),
        (1986, 17,'3AA',3),
        (1985,18,'3AA',3),
        (1985,19,'3AA',3),
        (NULL, 20,'3AC',3),
        (2005,21,'3AC',3),
        (2005, 22,'3AC',3),
        (2005,23,'3AC',3);
```

This is how I find the mode of the InDate for the Equipment within the ProcessID.

```
WITH CTE_CountofEquipment AS
 (
  SELECT
    ProcessID
   ,SiteID
   ,cnt   = COUNT(1)
   ,rid   = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProcessID ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC)
   ,InDate
    FROM dbo.Table_basic 
  GROUP BY  SiteID, ProcessID, InDate
 )
 SELECT
   ProcessID
  ,cnt = cnt
  ,[SiteID]
  ,InDate
 FROM CTE_CountofEquipment
 WHERE rid = 1
 ORDER BY SiteID;
```

I would like to use these determined modes to fill in the NULL InDate for a given ProcessID.

Desired result example:

```
(NULL, 3,'1PAA',1),
(2001, 3,'1PAA',1),
(2001, 3,'1PAA',1),
(1999, 3,'1PAA',1),
(2000, 3,'1PAA',1),
(2001, 3,'1PAA',1),
```

becomes

```
(2001, 3,'1PAA',1), -- InDate updated to modal value
(2001, 3,'1PAA',1),
(2001, 3,'1PAA',1),
(1999, 3,'1PAA',1),
(2000, 3,'1PAA',1),
(2001, 3,'1PAA',1),
```

Thanks

Comment: are you updating max value of InDate for a ProcessID='1PAA'??

Comment: I don't understand the result for the given example,can you plz elaborate

Comment: Hi Rams, no I am looking to update by mode of InDate for a ProcessID='1PAA'

Comment: TheGameiswar, please see edit. I have updated to make desired outcome clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do the calculation like this:

```
with modes as (
      select p.*
      from (select tb.processId, tb.indate, count(*) as cnt,
                   row_number() over (partition by tb.processId order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
            from table_basic tb
            group by tb.processId, tb.indate
           ) p
      where seqnum = 1
     )
update tb
    set indate = m.indate
    from table_basic tb join
         modes m
         on tb.processId = m.processId
    where indate is null;
```

This answers your *question*.  I have no idea why your calculation of the mode uses the `SiteId`.  That is not part of the question.  I don't know what the reference is to `NULL` values for `EquipmentId`.  That is not part of the question either.

However, you should be able to easily modify this for other groupings for the modes or other columns.

Comment: Brilliant, this did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the following to do the `UPDATE`:

```
;WITH CTE_CountofEquipment AS (
    SELECT InDate, ProcessID, SiteID, 
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcessID, SiteID, InDate) AS cnt
    FROM dbo.Table_basic
), ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT InDate, ProcessID, SiteID,
          FIRST_VALUE(InDate) 
          OVER 
             (PARTITION BY ProcessID, SiteID
             ORDER BY cnt DESC ) AS mode
    FROM CTE_CountofEquipment
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET InDate = mode
WHERE InDate IS NULL
```

The query uses window functions to calculate the `mode` value:

- `COUNT OVER()` is used in order to determine the population of each `InDate` slice within each `ProcessID, SiteID` partition
- `FIRST_VALUE(InDate) is used to select the`InDate` having the biggest population

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/BTBWA98182)